# How to scale a 2D vector (radius), retaining its angle

Tags: c#, wpf, vector

how can I change a radial vector of any length to some fixed length vector (radius-long or 1-long), retaining only its angle?
Given is mouse cursor X,Y; radius is a known constant.

My problem is - I have a mouse-drag dial control, I need output angles like 0 to 360 if clockwise, 0 to -360 if counterwise, starting from mouse-click or rotation direction change moment.
To make it work exactly as I want - it needs to consider mouse movement only around its circle dial, mouse movement away/to circle center must be ignored.

To have that - I need to use Vector.AngleBetween and Vector.CrossProduct, but:
parameter vectors must be of same length. How to make them same length?

Comment: Try and write some code. If you have a specific question about a spicific **programming** quesiton, we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Vector.Normalize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.normalize(v=vs.110).aspx) method to obtain vectors of length 1.

> A normalized vector maintains its direction but its Length becomes 1.
>   The resulting vector is often called a unit vector. A vector is
>   normalized by dividing the vector by its own Length.

By the way, the static `Vector.AngleBetween()` method does not require both vectors provided as arguments to be of the same length.